# Why won't GCC let me use a template parameter for another template's parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, g++, function-templates

I have written the following template function for summing the contents of a std::vector object. It is in a file by itself called sum.cpp.

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
T sum(const std::vector<T>* objs) {
    T total;
    std::vector<T>::size_type i;
    for(i = 0; i < objs->size(); i++) {
        total += (*objs)[i];
    }
    return total;
}
```

When I try to compile this function, G++ spits out the following error:

```
sum.cpp: In function ‘T sum(const std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >*)’:
sum.cpp:6: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘i’
sum.cpp:7: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
```

As far as I can tell the reason that this error is returned is because `std::vector<T>::size_type` cannot be resolved to a type. Is my only option here to fall back to `std::size_t` (which if I understand correctly is *often* but not *always* the same as `std::vector<T>::size_type`), or is there a workaround?

Comment: Oh no, not again :-) Seriously, this is the most common question about templates here, but irritatingly difficult to search for.

Comment: [Where and why do I have to put “template” and “typename” on dependent names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)

Comment: @Xeo - of the question poster knows about "typename" and what "dependent names" are, probably will know the answer by him/herself :D

Comment: @Kiril: I just posted that link as a reference. :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried searching for this but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Im so glad you like my littl faq entry. I put so much love into it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
typename std::vector<T>::size_type i;
```

http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#disambiguation

Comment: [Further reading material](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#typename)

Answer (score 3):

size_type is a dependent name, you need to prefix it with `typename`, i.e.:

```
typename std::vector<T>::size_type i;
```